# Why is amyloplast produced by some plant cells but not other cells?

Tags: botany

For example I know it is produced in Potato's and fruits and its purpose is to synthesize glucose in to starch through polymerization. But why is it only present in some cells? Is it only present in cells with higher glucose content?

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E.! If you need additional assistance, please visit [The Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Just a guess: fruits/seeds need starch for the nutrition of the seedling. For tubers I guess it is better to differentiate chloroplasts to amyloplasts in regions where there is no light exposure (chloroplasts won't be able to carry out photosynthesis). This differentiation is controlled by plant hormones and light exposure [also has a role](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1080872/).

Comment: amyloplast is just another form of chloroplast. The portion of a potato tuber (while attached to plant) gets light (have some unexposed position from ground) turns green.

Answer (score 1):

[Amyloplasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amyloplast?wprov=sfla1) are non pigmented organelles responsible for plant sugar storage, release and gravity perception (or tropism). This being the case they are commonly found in root caps (for gravity) and storage sites like tubers, fruits and grains.

So due to cell differentiation, it is not possible for these plastid organelles to be present in all cells the same way chloroplasts (another type of plastid) is not present in the stem (with the exception of small plants and succulents) and most of the root cells (Reece Urry et al, 2011).

**Reference**

Reece J.B., Urry L.A., Cain M.L., Wasserman S.A. et al (2011). “Campbell Biology 9th ed” Pearson Education, Inc., publishing as Pearson Benjamin Cummings, 1301 Sansome St., San Francisco, CA 94111.